# C - Readers/Writers (Concurrency): Forking & Semaphores Output

Tags: c, concurrency, fork, semaphore

I'm writing an implementation of the Reader's/Writer's Problem with Semaphores and Forking (which is required, instead of pthreads unfortunately).

It's reader preference, and basically a user specifies the numbers of readers/writers, and the program forks off the requested number of each. Writers pick a random number, write it to the critical section, and report it to the console. Readers simply report the current number.

I'm using semaphores to manage it, and for some reason, once a process gets ahold of the critical section it iterates through all of the predetermined number of loops before allowing the next process to access it. I feel like it may have something to do with my fork()-ing loops in main, although I'm not sure.

EDIT: Sorry if what I'm asking isn't completely clear; the output below shows each process (reader 1, writer 1, etc.) each accessing the critical section twice in a row (it would be 10x if I increased ITERATION to 10), which is not what I want. It should have a more random appearing output (each process accessing it once and then handing it off). I can't tell why each process is able to block off access like it is right now.

Below is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "asm/unistd.h"

#include <semaphore.h>

#define ITERATION 2

int *readCount, *crit_sec;
sem_t wrt, mutex, *s1, *s2;

void writer (int numWriter) {
    sem_wait(&wrt);
    *crit_sec = rand() % 100 + 1;
    printf("Writer %d - Wrote: %d\n", numWriter, *crit_sec);
    sem_post(&wrt);

    return;
}

void reader (int numReader) {
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    *readCount++;
    if (*readCount == 1) sem_wait(&wrt);
    sem_post(&mutex);
    printf("Reader %d - Read: %d\n", numReader, *crit_sec);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    *readCount--;
    if (*readCount==0) sem_post(&wrt);
    sem_post(&mutex);

    return;
}

int main (int argv, char **argc) {
    int numRead, numWrite;
    void *ptr1 = mmap(NULL, 2*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    void *ptr2 = mmap(NULL, 2*sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    crit_sec=ptr1, readCount=ptr1+1;
    *crit_sec=0, *readCount=0;

    s1=ptr2, s2=ptr2+1;
    *s1=mutex, *s2=wrt;
    sem_init(&mutex,1,1);
    sem_init(&wrt,1,1);

    if (argv !=3) {
            printf("Incorrect usage - must use: ./ReadersWriters [# readers] [# writers]\n");
            return 0;
    }

    if (sscanf (argc[1], "%i", &numRead)!=1|| sscanf (argc[2], "%i", &numWrite)!=1) {
            printf("Incorrect usage - must use: ./ReadersWriters [# readers] [# writers]\n");
            return 0;
    }

    int rcnt = 0;
    while (rcnt++ < numRead) {
            if (fork()==0) {
                    int i=0;        
                    for(;i<ITERATION;i++) reader(rcnt);
                    return;
            }
    } 

    int wcnt = 0;
    while (wcnt++ < numWrite) {
            if (fork()==0) {
                    int j=0;
                    for (;j<ITERATION;j++) writer(wcnt);
                    return;  
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is an example output (although the process order can differ):

```
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Writer 1 - Wrote: 84
Writer 1 - Wrote: 87
Reader 2 - Read: 87
Reader 2 - Read: 87
Writer 2 - Wrote: 84   
Writer 2 - Wrote: 87
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your problem / question?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I don't want each process to control the critical section multiple iterations in a row without handing it off. If I increased the ITERATION macro to 10, then you'd see each process access it 10 times in a row - which is useless.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, what I mean is that I don't want each process to control the
>   critical section multiple iterations in a row without handing it off.

The scheduler is not obliged to switch to another thread if one calls e. g. `sem_post()`, especially not with the standard scheduling policy `SCHED_OTHER` (see `man sched_setscheduler`). That said, with `#define ITERATION 5` I sometimes get e. g.:

```
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Reader 2 - Read: 0
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Reader 2 - Read: 0
Reader 1 - Read: 0
Reader 2 - Read: 0
Reader 2 - Read: 84
Reader 2 - Read: 84
Writer 1 - Wrote: 84
Writer 1 - Wrote: 87
Writer 2 - Wrote: 84
Writer 2 - Wrote: 87
Writer 2 - Wrote: 78
Writer 1 - Wrote: 78
Writer 2 - Wrote: 16
Writer 1 - Wrote: 16
Writer 2 - Wrote: 94
Writer 1 - Wrote: 94
```